# A movie about black activist whos ideas get turned down by racist radio producer only to become racist himself and get tortured and killed

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember watching this movie whilst abroad (they had a TV network that ran old 90s films) about a black man who was well off from other black men in his society had a job at a radio station that talks about hot topics. The owner of the radio station is extremely racist and uses the word "nigger" frequently perhaps it was because it was frequent at the time (the movie is set in America, during a racist era I couldn't pinpoint which one but they were well past slavery but America still discriminated blacks, not sure about segregation either).

Anyways the owner always played things that were extremely racist and the black man (main character) would hint at ideas about radio broadcasts that would empower black people; he found some of the things his owner said disgusting and I think he hated him.

Now for some reason (I don't remember) the main character decided (as a joke?) to hire some people to black face and be incredibly racist on the radio show (for satire?). I think the point of this was to get bad reviews from the public and to take down the radio show, in fact it did quite the opposite and it got tons of good reviews from being in the paper and etc.

Eventually the fame got to the main characters head and even though he is black himself started to make the show more dark and racist, the radio member crew were all fine with it except some people who got really disturbed.

In the film theres a gang of people (pretty much the anti-KKK) who were black activists; I think they were white themselves decided they need to take matters in to their own hands and in order to stop the radio company they took hostage/tortured and killed some of the radio members the main character hired near the begining.

Police eventually shoot and kill all of these Anti-KKK members and the relative of one of the Anti-KKK members (I think Mum or Sister) kidnaps the main character, tortures him and accidentally shoots him whilst fighting for the gun. I think the movie ends with the woman playing things that the radio posted and we see the main character dead in the final scene...

Comment: Are you sure its a radio show because it might be bamboozled

Answer (score 12):

**Is it [*Bamboozled (2000)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboozled)?**

If you replace Radio with TV show it sounds like the plot to Bamboozled.

According to Wikipedia:

> Pierre Delacroix (whose real name is Peerless Dothan) is an uptight, Harvard University-educated black man, working for the television network CNS. At work, he has to endure torment from his boss Thomas Dunwitty, a tactless, boorish white man. Not only does Dunwitty use AAVE, and use the word "nigger" repeatedly in conversations, he also proudly proclaims that he is more black than Delacroix and that he can use nigger since he is married to a black woman and has two mixed-race children. Dunwitty frequently rejects Delacroix's scripts for television series that portray black people in positive, intelligent scenarios, dismissing them as "Cosby clones".

**The reason he made the racist show:**

> In an effort to escape his contract through being fired, Delacroix develops a minstrel show with the help of his personal assistant Sloane Hopkins. Mantan: The New Millennium Minstrel Show features black actors in blackface, extremely racist jokes and puns, and offensively stereotyped CGI-animated cartoons that caricature the leading stars of the new show.

**The Crew he hires:**

> Delacroix and Hopkins recruit two impoverished street performers – Manray, named after American artist Man Ray, and Womack – to star in the show. While Womack is horrified when Delacroix tells him details about the show, Manray sees it as his big chance to become rich and famous for his tap-dancing skills.

**The main character in this also dies due to second degree murder:**

> During a struggle over the gun, Delacroix is shot in the stomach. Hopkins, horrified, flees while proclaiming that it was Delacroix's own fault that he got shot.